# Converting Date Format in SQL Server - Getting Data Type Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to convert my date to a different format but running into issues.

Currently, my date column looks like:

```
YearBuilt
1934-01-01 00:00:00:0000
1981-01-01 00:00:00:0000
```

I'd like to have it be:

```
YearBuilt
01/01/1934 00:00:00:0000
01/01/1981 00:00:00:0000
```

I tried

```
update table set YearBuilt = '01/01/' + YearBuilt
```

But get the error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

But my YearBuilt column is already a datetime data type, so I'm not sure which string it's trying to convert.

Any input would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Date/times are stored in SQL in an internal format.  That is a good thing!  You should specify the format on output.  That is, you can do:

```
select '01/01/' + datename(year, YearBuilt)
```

You can build this into the table:

```
alter table t add YearBuilt_str as ('01/01/' + datename(year, YearBuilt))
```

Then just use the string version to get the alternative format.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to retain the time stamp when doing this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @D DateTime = '2017-11-01 00:00:00:000';

SELECT @D AS Input,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(50) , @D, 101) +
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @D, 113), 12, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @D, 113))) AS OutPut;
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+------------------------+
|        Input        |         OutPut         |
+---------------------+------------------------+
| 01.11.2017 00:00:00 | 1/11/2017 00:00:00:000 |
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

When your column has `Date Time` datatype, then you can't update the date with your custom date format.

But, you can select your date with your Custom format by `SQL` Query:

```
SELECT '01/01/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(YearBuilt))+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(YearBuilt AS TIME)) [YearBuilt]
FROM <table_name>;
```

Result :

```
YearBuilt
01/01/1934 00:00:00.0000000
01/01/1981 00:00:00.0000000
```